# how to solve SocketError: getaddrinfo: No such host is known in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have write Ruby code to connect one system to another

I got the following error

```
SocketError: getaddrinfo: No such host is known.
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/t
ransport/session.rb:67:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/t
ransport/session.rb:67:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/t
ransport/session.rb:67:in `block in initialize'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:52:in `timeout'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:97:in `timeout'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/t
ransport/session.rb:67:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh.r
b:200:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh.r
b:200:in `start'
        from (irb):6
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

how to solve this error

My code is

```
require "net/ssh"
require "net/sftp"
HOST = "192.168.2.178"
USER = "sivakumar.m"
PASSWORD = "star123"
Net::SSH.start( "HOST", "USER", :password => PASSWORD ) do |ssh|
ssh.sftp.connect
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to ping this ip?

Answer (score 3):

Here is your problem. You are sending the string names "HOST" and "USER" not the variable. Change it to this

```
Net::SSH.start( HOST, USER, :password => PASSWORD ) do |ssh|
```